# what's the difference between the AWS API Gateway and Interface Endpoint

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

### I'm confused with those concept API Gateway, Gateway endpoint and interface endpoint. Is API Gateway always in a public VPC?  In below question, answer is B. I don't understand the difference between API Gateway and interface endpoint.

A company uses Amazon API Gateway to run a private gateway with two REST APIs in the same VPC. The BuyStock RESTful web service calls the CheckFunds RESTful web service to ensure that enough funds are available before a stock can be purchased. The company has noticed in the VPC flow logs that the BuyStock RESTful web service calls the CheckFunds RESTful web service over the internet instead of through the VPC. A solutions architect must implement a solution so that the APIs communicate through the VPC.

Which solution will meet these requirements with the FEWEST changes to the code?

A. Add an X-API-Key header in the HTTP header for authorization.

B. Use an interface endpoint. (Most Voted)

C. Use a gateway endpoint.

D. Add an Amazon Simple Queue Service (Amazon SQS) queue between the two REST APIs.

Who can explain the difference between API Gateway and interface endpoint in a VPC?

Answer (score 2):

API Gateway and VPC Endpoints are two completely different services.

API Gateway is a fully managed and serverless service used to define, map, and expose APIs, typically but not exclusively, RESTful ones. An API Gateway can either be public (exposed on the internet) or private (accessible only within a VPC, but only if is a REST API Gateway).

Interface and Gateway Endpoints (also known as VPC Endpoints) are methods for connecting to AWS services from within VPC resources, such as EC2 instances or ECS containers, without going through internet traffic (i.e., without using a NAT Gateway). 
I won't delve into the differences between Interface and Gateway Endpoints here, but for the purposes of your study, it's important to note that Gateway Endpoints are available only for S3 and DynamoDB. 
In contrast, Interface Endpoints are available for all other AWS services except for DynamoDB.

For further readings:

- [AWS API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/welcome.html)
- [VPC Endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-privatelink/what-are-vpc-endpoints.html)

Comment: ya, then the answer to the question I post is very strange. API Gateway can be either public and private. In the question statement said, the API Gateway is private,  then how can it be accessed from internet?

Comment: yes, the question is strange because you can access a private API Gateway only with an Interface Endpoint: where did you found this question?

Comment: I found it on examtopics.com, SAA-C03, question 360.   Here is the link   https://www.examtopics.com/discussions/amazon/view/100238-exam-aws-certified-solutions-architect-associate-saa-c03/

Answer (score 0):

### API Gateway Endpoint:

Amazon API Gateway is a managed service that allows you to create, publish, and manage APIs for your applications. An API Gateway endpoint refers to the URL that clients can use to interact with your APIs. It acts as a front door for your APIs, providing features like authentication, rate limiting, caching, and request/response transformations. API Gateway endpoints are used to expose your RESTful APIs or WebSocket APIs to external clients, including web or mobile applications.

### Interface Endpoint (Amazon VPC Interface Endpoint):

Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) interface endpoints allow you to connect privately to AWS services from within your VPC without needing to traverse the public internet. These endpoints provide a way to access AWS services like Amazon S3, DynamoDB, and more, from your VPC over a private network connection. Interface endpoints are used to ensure secure and low-latency communication between resources within your VPC and AWS services, without exposing your traffic to the public internet.

In the given scenario, the BuyStock RESTful web service should be calling the CheckFunds RESTful web service through the VPC, but it's currently going over the internet. So that is the reason we need to opt **Interface Endpoint** in this case.